# Opening Range from a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some VBA to check for changes to a spreadsheet when a button is clicked.  The spreadsheet makes a copy of itself in the temp directory as determined by the environment variable on Workbook_Open().  This is all working fine, but the problem is with my button_click sub.

Following advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015693/getting-a-range-from-a-closed-workbook-into-an-array) question, I'm trying to read the range of interest into an array.  The problem is, my array is coming up empty.  Is there something stupid that I'm forgetting to do here?

```
Dim wsOriginalWS As Worksheet
Dim varOriginalSheet As Variant
Dim wbkOrig As Workbook
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim varOriginalSheet As Variant

'... some other non-relevant things

strRangeToCheck = "A5:HC231"
Set wbkOrig = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileStr)
Set wsOriginalWS = wbkOrig.Worksheets("Sheet1")
wsOriginalWS.Activate
With wsOriginalWS
    Set varOriginalSheet = Range(strRangeToCheck)
End With

'... some other non-relevant things.  At this point,
'... wbkOrig is still open, and I can see it with all of its data
'... while debugging.

itemp = getDimension(varOriginalSheet)
```

I have verified that everything up to `Set varOriginalSheet = Range(strRangeToCheck)` is working.  The spreadsheet in the temp directory opens and is not empty.  For some reason varOriginalSheet is empty.

Here's getDimensions:

```
Function getDimension(var As Variant) As Long
    On Error GoTo Err
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tmp As Long
    i = 0
    Do While True
        i = i + 1
        tmp = UBound(var, i)
    Loop
Err:
    getDimension = i - 1
End Function
```

Comment: Try: `Set varOriginalSheet = .Range(strRangeToCheck)`. Without the point its just a general range and not directly refering to `wsOriginalWS`. Also you dont need `wsOriginalWS.Activate`.

Comment: Thanks - this is a good point, but it still comes up empty.

Comment: Ah okay, you also need `getDimension(Application.Transpose(varOriginalSheet))` to convert it to an array.

Comment: Add `.Value` on the end.

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` in the `'... some other non-relevant things`?

Comment: @UGP Thanks, I included getDimensions thinking that the problem might be with that rather than actually getting the data into the array, but after further debugging, the array is definitely empty.  I will make these changes though.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Add .Value to the end of .Range(strRangeToCheck)?  Also, I don't have an On Error in some other non relevant things.  It steps through the entire code in debug mode without throwing any errors.

Comment: Yes at the end of that line.

Comment: Adding .Value to the end of .Range(strRangeToCheck) results in a type mismatch error.

Comment: Oh and do not use Set when setting a variant array. `varOriginalSheet = Range(strRangeToCheck).Value`