# Extract data from a closed workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Error Received: Run-Time error '1004'. Application-defined or object-defined error. I've searched the forum for similar topics but could never get a good answer. I am trying to extract data from a closed workbook. Here is sample of my code. I need the last row from the source data, but there are many workbooks and each one will have a different last row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFromClosedWorkbook2()
' Defines variables
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook 
Dim fname As String, fpath As String, shtname As String
Dim tgtlr As Long
Dim current_lcn As Long
Dim current_row As Long
Dim i As Long: i = 2
' Disable screen updating to reduce screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Define which workbook is which
current_lcn = Cells(2, 3).Value
Set wb1 = Workbooks("RBOM test.xlsm")
tgtlr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
fpath = "C:\users\folder1\My Documents\folder2\folder3\"
fname = "filename.xlsx": shtname = "filename"
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ2:FO2")
  .Formula = "=INDEX('" & fpath & "[" & fname & "]" & shtname & "'!A:A,  COUNTA('" & fpath & "[" & fname & "]" & shtname & "'!$A:$A)-1)"
  .Value = .Value
End With

' Re-enable screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

the filename is the same as the shtname

I eventually want to get it so where it'll loop through the rest of the files. But since I've haven't found a way to do this without opening the workbook. I've read that someone developed a code where you didn't have to open the workbook, but you needed the range pre determined, whereas mine is different depending on the last row. The last part of the code was my attempt at the beginning of incorporating the code into a for loop and pasting the data down with the same criteria.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulling data from a closed workbook macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952856/pulling-data-from-a-closed-workbook-macro)

Comment: I tried changing by using the above link as an example. So after .copy I have:
    destination:=wb1.sheets("Sheet1").range(Cells(2,43), Cells(2,171)), but I still get the error:

Comment: include your updates in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44144215/edit) and avoid from putting them into comments.

Comment: You can link to the question I provide and say that in reference to that you applied following changes in your code and you get the same error or different error on the specific part of your code

Comment: It's simple. You can't! You have to open existing workbook before you start copying data.

Comment: it has been edited accordingly. I had to where it actually did copy and paste, but I made some other changes and can't fix what I have changed.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to replace this part

> ```
> Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(...)
> ....
> wb2.Close
> ```

With some formula that references the closed WB and catches automatically its last row. For this you need to have a column in the source sheet that is always populated. Suppose this column is `A`. You can try to replace the code above with this:

```
Dim fName As String, fPath As String, shtName As String
fPath = "C:\Users\folder1\My Documents\folder2\folder3\"
fName = "filename.xlsx": shtName = "mySheet"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ2:FO2")
  .Formula = "=INDEX('" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & shtName & _
    "'!A:A, COUNTA('" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & shtName & "'!$A:$A)-1)"
  .Value = .Value
End With
```

This will fetch the last row from the closed WB through a formula, then fix the value. Now you can loop on many workbooks using `Dir` (for example),  by changing each time the variable `fName`.

p.s.: setting a formula and making it working without opening the WB works very well with Excel files (i.e `.xlsx`) but less well with `.csv` files, where the formula needs that the WB opens to refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely transfer your input into the file. When the source data is exported into the specified folder, it's automatically saved as the .csv file type. I don't believe there is any way to change the file type without opening the file and resaving it as a .xlsx or .xlsm.

Comment: How does it store the number of rows from the closed file. 

It definitely got rid of the error that was popping up. Now its just a matter of looping the other files together. Now I'm kind of new to vba, but have some programming experience, but what is the    dir   tag.

Comment: I tried running it, and it runs without errors. I don't have access to my original data so I made makeshift data at home, but I don't see how the data from the source file, (A & the last row, DY and the last row) is being pasted to the targeted location. (AQ to FO).

Comment: @Jeff what is the result you observe in `AQ2:FO2`?

Comment: But I nitpicked at it and a dialog managed to appear asking to: "update: copying file." but linked to the destination folder, but still nothing was pasted to the target workbook

Comment: @Jeff are you sure that you have modified properly the `fPath`, `fName` and `shtName`? Please verify that, and try it once on a `.xlsx` file. Because in my tests it worked perfectly with xlsx files but displayed `#value` in case of csv files until I just open the file (manually or by code).

Comment: Yes. I have verified that the fpath, fname and shtname are correct. I had to use the concatenate function for the filename as that will change when I loop back around. I have not tried with it a .xlsx file.

I will save one of the files that are labeled as .csv and save it as a .xlsx file and see if it works then and get back to you.

Since it was my understanding that you had to open the closed workbook to copy the data, I managed to get the pre-existing code to work and managed to loop through. I will insert my code as an "answer" when I get a chance.

Comment: But I have come across another problem in that when I run my macro, my excel file will be unresponsive afterwards. I will attempt to scroll using bar and the sheet won't scroll. When I click on a cell, a yellow diamond shape with an exclamation point will pop up.

Comment: I changed the code to above to your template. I tried it and still nothing. What file do I select when the dialogue for update appears?