# Pull data from a series of closed Excel workbooks with changing names

Tags: vba, excel, getvalue

So I have a main workbook (we'll call it Workbook One), that needs to pull a single cell worth of data, typically in a percentage form, from a series of other workbooks, and deposit it in a column when a button is clicked. The other workbook's pathing is listed in Workbook One. However the pathing is built dynamically. So, the workbook name is built from input in cell A1 as such: =A1 & ".xlsx", with the drive and folder pathing pulled like so: =N1 & N2 & N3, etc as necessary depending on number of folders and drive name. It all comes out into one cell that reads the full pathing, but if necessary I can (and have been) pulling bits and pieces separately.

My end goal is to have a macro activated by a button that runs through a list of workbooks pulling the data in the one cell from each and depositing it in a series of cells in Workbook One. Also that list may contain blanks, so if possible, skipping blank cells. Also, I am not stuck with this code, so if you have a better way of doing it, please let me know.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Function dynamicPull()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim sourceRange As Integer, inputRow As Integer, fepTotal As Integer
fepTotal = Range("EventList!F2").Value 'total number of events to run through
sourceRange = 2
inputRow = 3

Dim sourceFile As String, inputRange As String, pullRange As String, pullData As String
sourceFile = Range("Settings!Q" & sourceRange).Value 'currently unused
pullRange = Range("Settings!$N$23").Value 'cell to pull from in series of workbooks

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbMain As Workbook
Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook

Dim sourceFile1 As String, sourceFile2 As String, sourceFile3 As String
sourceFile1 = Range("Settings!$N$26").Value 'pathing to workbook, ie C:\Folder1\Folder2\
sourceFile2 = Range("Settings!R" & sourceRange).Value 'workbook name
sourceFile3 = "Cover Sheet" 'sheet name

If fepTotal >= 1 Then
 checkedEvents = 0 'checkedEvents is dimmed in declarations
 error = 0
 For pullLoop = 1 To fepTotal
  sourceRange = 2
  inputRow = 3
  inputRange = "D" & inputRow 'where i want the pulled data to go
  sourceFile2 = Range("Settings!R" & sourceRange).Value 'workbook name
  pullData = GetValue(sourceFile1, sourceFile2, sourceFile3, pullRange)
  If pullData = "FnF" Then
   'wbMain.Sheets("EventList").Range(inputRange).Value = "FnF"
   GoTo FnF
  Else
   wbMain.Sheets("EventList").Range(inputRange).Value = pullData
   checkedEvents = checkedEvents + 1
  End If
FnF:
  inputRow = inputRow + 1 'shifts to next input cell (D4, D5, etc)
  sourceRange = sourceRange + 1 'shifts to next cell containing next document pathing
 Next pullLoop
Else
 error = MsgBox("No event inputs to derive from.", vbCritical, "ERROR")
 error = 1
End If

sourceRange = 2 'resets sourceRange to first pull cell
inputRow = 3
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Function

'Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
'    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
'    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
'    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
'     GetValue = "FnF"
'     Exit Function
'    End If
'   Create the argument
'    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
'     Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
'    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
'End Function

Function GetValue(ByVal sPath As String, sFile As String, _
              sSht As String, sRng As String) As Variant
' Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
' VBA only
Dim sArg As String

If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

If Len(Dir(sPath & sFile)) Then 'Runtime error 52: Bad file name or number
    sArg = "'" & sPath & _
           "[" & sFile & "]" & _
           sSht & "'!" & _
           Application.ConvertFormula(sRng, xlA1, xlR1C1, True)
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(sArg)
Else
    GetValue = "File not found"
End If
End Function
```

I've found several other posts that may be useful:

[Pulling from closed workbook - Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952856/pulling-data-from-a-closed-workbook-macro)

[GetValue function - The Spreadsheet Page](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/)

I have struggled with this for quite some time and any and all help is GREATLY appreciated. I'll answer any questions, provide any feedback, etc as quickly as possible. Thanks again.

Comment: In each work book do they contain a table with headers if so are they all different? You have to find the static differences for each workbook. after that it would be easy to tell them apart from each other.

Comment: Could you specify what is the problem? Is your code working, but not giving expected results? Some error occurs?

Comment: @Quint The series of workbooks I am pulling from, I only want to pull cell K15 on Cover Sheet. "Cover Sheet" is covered by sourceFile3, while cell K15 is covered by pullRange.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the line that errors and then check the values of `sPath` and `sFile` - one of them is apparently not valid.

Comment: click on the line where you want it to stop, and press F9. The line will turn red, indicating a break point. the program will pause on that line and you can check your variables.

Comment: What are the values for your path and file? is it possible you have an extra backslash in one of them?

Comment: @braX There was an additional apostrophe in front of the drive. Good catch and thank you. The code will now pull one document's data, however it won't move past the first one. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you need to move the code that sets your sourcefile variables inside of your loop otherwise you are just reading the same files over and over.

Comment: @braX So I added the changing variables to the For loop, however it still is just copying the one cell. I think it is because they reset back to the default ranges of 2 and 3 for sourceRange and inputRow at the start of every loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The working code is as follows:

```
Function dynamicPull()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim sourceRange As Integer, inputRow As Integer, fepTotal As Integer
fepTotal = Range("EventList!F2").Value

Dim inputRange As String, pullRange As String, pullData As String
pullRange = Range("Settings!$N$23").Value

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbMain As Workbook
Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook

Dim sourceFile1 As String, sourceFile2 As String, sourceFile3 As String
sourceFile1 = Range("Settings!$N$26").Value 'pathing to workbook, ie C:\Folder1\Folder2\
sourceFile3 = "Cover Sheet" 'sheet name

If fepTotal >= 1 Then
 checkedEvents = 0
 error = 0
 For pullLoop = 1 To fepTotal
 If pullLoop = 1 Then
  sourceRange = 2
  inputRow = 3
 End If
 inputRange = "D" & inputRow
 sourceFile2 = Range("Settings!R" & sourceRange).Value 'workbook name
 pullData = GetValue(sourceFile1, sourceFile2, sourceFile3, pullRange)
 If pullData = "FnF" Then
  GoTo FnF
 Else
 wbMain.Sheets("EventList").Range(inputRange).Value = pullData
 checkedEvents = checkedEvents + 1
End If
FnF:
 inputRow = inputRow + 1
 sourceRange = sourceRange + 1
Next pullLoop
Else
 error = MsgBox("No event inputs to derive from.", vbCritical, "ERROR")
 error = 1
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Function

Function GetValue(ByVal sPath As String, sFile As String, _
              sSht As String, sRng As String) As Variant
' Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
' VBA only
Dim sArg As String

If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

If Len(Dir(sPath & sFile)) Then
    sArg = "'" & sPath & _
           "[" & sFile & "]" & _
           sSht & "'!" & _
           Application.ConvertFormula(sRng, xlA1, xlR1C1, True)
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(sArg)
Else
    GetValue = "NO DATA"
End If
End Function
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I commented throughout the code to explain some of the variables, etc. Thanks again for all the help.