# Excel UDF to reference table in closed workbook for lookup

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a working UDF which assigns a user name based on the first letter of a selected cell. The alphabet and user name list are built into the function in VBA therefore updates are tedious so I'm searching for an alternative.

I created a table within a workbook where the assignments can be updated more easily and by anyone.  I've made several efforts however I cannot get the UDF to properly assign user name by looking up the table.  One attempt is below, either I'm way off the mark or this cannot be done.  Thoughts?

```
Function Test(Optional Cell As String) As String
Dim Name As Variant, Alpha As Variant, ATable As Variant
Dim i As Integer

If UCase(Left(Cell, 1)) = "A" Then
    Alpha = UCase(Left(Cell, 2))
Else: Alpha = UCase(Left(Cell, 1))
End If

ATable = Workbook("C:\filepath\").Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("ALPHA").DataBodyRange.Value

For i = LBound(ATable) To UBound(ATable)
    If ATable(i, 1) = Alpha Then
        Name = ATable(i, 2)
    End If
Next i

Test = Name

End Function
```

The UDF is designed to be used in any open workbook and table workbook would be closed.

Comment: A workbook must be open to be part of the `Workbooks` collection.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a `Workbook_Open` or `Workbook_Activate` macro that retrieved the latest Table from the external table workbook, copy it to a hidden sheet, and just use a `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: It will likely be the way I have to go however I was attempting to complete as a UDF as this is the preference for end-users.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get a data from a closed workbook you have to open it - [Pulling data from a closed workbook macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952856/pulling-data-from-a-closed-workbook-macro)
2. A `UDF` cannot open a workbook. [Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

Comment: What I was afraid of. Thank you for clarifying.