# Excel formula without open worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one report which is all time updated and changed the file name. I want to know is it possible to make a formula (Except for Mecro code) to another worksheet without open this worksheet.

I am using indirect formula but it required to open worksheet.

Comment: it's hard to read data without opening it. And I think this is the wrong forum.

Answer (score 0):

[Both](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExtractFromClosedWorkbook.htm) of [these sources](https://www.exceltip.com/keyboard-other-shortcuts-in-vba/pull-data-from-a-closed-workbook.html) indiciate that this cannot be done with a formula alone. However, they propose workaround solutions using vba code, as well as [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952856/pulling-data-from-a-closed-workbook-macro)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use PowerQuery. Though it uses M language, you can use it with GUI. If your version of Excel is prior than 2013, you must install the addon